# Trigger different iterm color scheme when entering vim

Tags: vim, terminal, themes, iterm2, iterm

I'm fairly new to Vim but I have been always using iTerm as my main terminal.

I'm on OSX as you may expect and I have a theme defined for iTerm, but I wanted to know if it is possible to trigger a different theme when I enter on Vim. In this case I'm using Homebrew theme as my main iTerm theme, but when I enter Vim I want it to change the theme to Cobalt2 (only for the window with Vim).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way would be to define an alias, function, or shell script to run in place of vim. Call it 'vim' and have it change the colors, run the real vim, and unchange the colors.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if it is possible to trigger a different theme when I enter on Vim.

Yes, you can change it using `:colorscheme scheme_name`, But cobalt2 scheme does not seem to be shipped by default. You can iterate the list by `:colo <TAB>`. 
For setting it permenantly, we need to set it in `~/.vimrc`.

> In this case I'm using Homebrew theme as my main iTerm theme, but when I enter Vim I want it to change the theme to Cobalt2 (only for the window with Vim).

Apparently, `cobalt2` is not shipped by default on vim, Hence we need to install it first. 
The usual procedure is to place the sheme file in `~/.vim/colors`. Create the `colors` folder, if not existing in `~/.vim`.

Google search give few links like [cobalt2-vim](https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/cobalt2-vim-theme.git). If this does not help, then you might like to pick a colorscheme of your liking from [here](http://cocopon.me/app/vim-color-gallery/).

This might not exactly solves your query but hopes. it helps